# "A Hero widget cannot be the descendant of another Hero widget" issue when showing SnackBar() widget

Tags: flutter

I have wrapped a Scaffold with a Hero. When opening a subpage out of the drawer and showing a SnackBar() widget, with

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

I get the error

```
A Hero widget cannot be the descendant of another Hero widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart':
Failed assertion: line 375 pos 7: 'context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Hero>() == null'
```

found a solution that fixed the issue temporary:

adding a Global Key to the Scaffold

```
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

and calling the snackbar with

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState..showSnackBar(snackBar); //this is working but deprecated
```

also tried

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext).showSnackBar(snackBar); //also leads to the error with the Hero
```

Edit - filed an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79359

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Hero` animation on `Scaffold` since it has hero animation inside it,
specifically on `FloatingActionButton`, if you have fab in your `Scaffold` try removing it, else add a `Container` as body of the `Scaffold` and wrap that. with `Hero`

Comment: Sure I can. but when I only wrap the body with a Hero, there is no animation to the appbar

Comment: haha, sorry.. I'm using it for a page transition animation from a container to a new page @nt4f04und

Comment: @nt4f04und please have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/animations - this is the transition effect I want to achieve